# Placing an element vertically centered on either side of the page

Tags: html, css

I am having a `<div>` element and want to set the`< div>` vertically center aligned to the left or right of the page.

```
<div id="qrcode">Content</div>
```

Below is the CSS I tried:

```
#qrcode{
    position:absolute;
    left:100%;
    margin-top:200px;
    margin-left:-200px;
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
}
```

But this not work fine when the size of the `<div>` changes.
What should be the properties so that it works regardless of the size of `<div>`?

Comment: Hello downvoter.. can you tell me the reason for your downvote?

Comment: why don't you just use float: left or float: right? and lose the position: absolute. This question really needs more context to get a proper answer!

Comment: I did not downvote you. But do you have searched for a solution in the first place? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-a-div-in-a-div

Comment: I know nothing on CSS and just trying to learn with some examples. Please let me know what content you need on this apart from the code. I believe I have provided the required code I have tried.

Comment: Nico: I want to center the div in a page. The example u provided is for div.

Comment: What do you mean by *left centre or in right centre*...?

Comment: @Purus there are a lot of other examples there, that do not rely on a certain parent item. You always have the `body` element. Here are a few examples: http://jsfiddle.net/41a81061/

Comment: @TJ : I mean at the right side of the page..

Comment: @NicoO : Its again aligns the DIV in the center of the page and not the right corner of the page. I have tried to search in the SO.

Comment: @Purus *Right* is not center, that is *right*... Your question is unclear as it is... please elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to vertically center align an element on the right side of the page you can use the translate technique like:

```css
#qrcode {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0; /*or left*/
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: hotpink;
}
```

```html
<div id="qrcode">Content</div>
```

Basically, `top:50%` positions the top of the element at the vertical center of the page and `translateY(-50%)` pushes it `50%`  upwards on `y` axis, relative to it's own size - positioning it on the vertical center of the page. `right:0` simply positions it at the right side.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily center the `<div>` like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="qrcode">Content</div>
```

CSS:

```
#qrcode{
    background: black;
    color: white;
    width:80px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    height:80px;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hp2d8n9s/4/)**

Comment: I am looking to center the div related to the entire page at the left or right side. But this about div relative to another div.

Comment: Based on your edited code, I am looking to center the div at RIGHT or LEFT side.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
position: fixed;
margin: auto;
height: 80px;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
```

and add `left: 0` or `right: 0` depending on where you want it.

```css
.qrcode{
  position: fixed;
  margin: auto;
  height: 80px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: red;
}
.qrcode.left {
  left: 0;
}
.qrcode.right {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="qrcode left">Content</div>
<div class="qrcode right">Content</div>
```